# Chained Dropdown(s) and Textbox in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a use case for a design:
*There are students who have to pay their fees every month in a class.*

So I am trying to do the following:
1. Dropdown #1: Contains Student Names
2. Dropdown #2: Contains Month Names
3. Textbox: Contains Fees amount for the selected month.

I am using the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myDropdown").change(function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    $("#txtBox").val(selectedValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tab1">
  <tr>
    <td>Select Affiliate Source:</td>
    <td>
      <select id="myDropdown">
        <option value="jan" label="2000">January</option>
        <option value="apr" label="2500">April</option>
        <option value="jul" label="2000">July</option>
        <option value="oct" label="2500">October</option>
      </select>
      <div>
        <input id="txtBox" type="text" readonly='1'>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

taken from stackoverflow. but i am unable to:
1. add a dropdown (for students) in a chained fashion, such that once a student is selected only then the months dropdown gets active.
2. once a month is selected, the value in its *label* attribute should be displayed in the textbox.

Any inputs will be more than appreciated.

Regards,
GenXCoders

Comment: Why transfer the value of one type of form input to another? As in, what do you gain by transferring the value of the `select` to a text `input`?

Comment: @Utkanos Actually I am not wanting to transfer the value. I am using couchcms. And as the coding is permitting me to only have the fees amount in the label attribute, i am wanting to get it there. But for calculation purposes, I am also having it saved from the input to the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Enable `month` select box `onchange` of `student` select box.
2. Get the value of `month` select box on `onchange` and set in text box.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#student").change(function() {
  $('#month').prop('disabled', false);
   
  });
    $("#month").change(function() {
 
    var selectedValue = $('#month :selected').attr('label');
    $("#txtBox").val(selectedValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tab1">
  <tr>
    <td>Select Affiliate Source:</td>
    <td>
    <select id="student">
  <option value="Student1">Student1</option>
  <option value="Student2">Student2</option>
  <option value="Student3">Student3</option>
</select>

<select id="month" disabled>
 <option value="jan" label="2000">January</option>
        <option value="apr" label="2500">April</option>
        <option value="jul" label="2000">July</option>
        <option value="oct" label="2500">October</option>
</select>
      <div>
        <input id="txtBox" type="text" readonly='1'>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what changes will I have to do in: var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    $("#txtBox").val(selectedValue); to get the value of the label attribute rather than the value attribute.

Comment: $('#month :selected').attr('label')

Comment: thanks a lot buddy. works like a charm. the best part, couchcms can easily be retrofitted into your code.